# Five different things and five different clues and five different-----

Tags: word, knowledge, no-computers

Please finish the title of this puzzle!

> Five different things, quite common
>
> All come in different size, shape and colour
>
> Each word has 3 different consonants
>
> Five words share and show the 3 same consonants at same exact location
>
> Look at them carefully

See anything special?

No programming please

Example only

> Let us say the words are  12A3E  12I3E 12O3A 12A3O 12E3U  The consonants are 1,2 and 3 and are in exact same location in every word. They can appear twice also in the same word. All words must fit the size, shape and colour requirements.

Comment: I added the no-computers tag, it seemed like that's what you want.

Comment: Off the top off my head, I can come up with at least a handful of such word sets, so I’m guessing hundreds of them  must exist. Apart from the three consonants bit, the other clues are very vague, so it’s hard to tell if I am looking carefully at  the correct word set.

Comment: 5 seemingly random words with 3 shared consonants at the same location. Seems like a brute force without using the computer.

Comment: And, on behalf of the grammar Gestapo, it is consonants, not consonents.

Comment: I also noticed the [knowledge] tag. Is it about 'knowing' these words or is some kind of slang involved?  Would the Language tag fit as well?

Comment: @ DEEM - Can an action -'Look at them carefully' be a clue ? I am wondering how...:-)?

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay The clue from the title and Look at them are related. How eill you complete the title? -- and Five different------?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Instead of carping about it in the comments, you have an Edit button for a reason. Feel free to use it to correct spelling and grammar errors in  puzzles where the "errors" aren't likely to be part of the puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

FURTHER and FURTHER EDIT- there is a change in my options
I guess these are

> BALLS,
>  BELLS,
>  BILLS,
>  [BOLLS](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGRV_enIN784IN784&ei=L8QsW-7WMKWWmAWumqOIAw&q=define%20boll&oq=define%20boll&gs_l=psy-ab.3...185615.186178.0.186478.4.4.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..4.0.0....0.qawQ4gg1Tks),
>  BULLS

And common letters(consonants) are

> B, L and S at the same position in all these 5 words.

To complete the title of the puzzle-

> Five different things and five different clues and five different -words(All are plurals ) each having one different vowel( a, e, i, o, u).

Comment: I can't see three same consonents in your answer!

Comment: This answer and puzzle reminds me of this, https://xkcd.com/169/

Comment: What is with: at same exact location

Comment: Same 3 consonents in all words must be used at the same exact location. Like Bread and Broad. B, R and D are same consonents in exact same location. Of course you can use any of these consonents twice in the same word

Comment: These words don't have any associated size or colour.

Comment: bolls are white, bills can be green, silver bells, red bulls, and ... vulgar.